# How to create pair game using node values and set a setTimeout() method

Tags: javascript

I want to create a pair game that if the same textnode is matched it will set the background in white to reveal the matched textnode if not it will set a timeout and get back in original state.
The Problem of this is if I use the childNodes.nodeValue in match it saids that ChildNodes.nodeValue is not a function. And I try another code. I declare a variable that calls the element tag name of div which is I append a textNode in div. I want to compare two consecutive childNodes of div and if it is the same node, I change the color of the background to white. and I use the setTimout method, if not the color of background will go back again in original state which is black, I am pretty confused about this.

can you scan my code and help me to figure out what is the problem of this code?

here is the code.

```
 <html>
  <head>
  <style>
   div.row {
   clear : left;
   margin: auto;
   width: 520px;   
 } 
 div.col {width:100px;
      height:100px;
      border: 3px solid black;
      float : left;
      margin: 10px;
      font-size: 75px;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: black;
    }
   </style>
   </head>
   <body>
  <div class="row">
  <div id="00" class="col"></div>  
  <div id="01"class="col"></div>
  <div id="02"class="col"></div>
  <div id="03"class="col"></div>
</div>  
<div class="row">
  <div id="10" class="col"></div>  
  <div id="11"class="col"></div>
  <div id="12"class="col"></div>
  <div id="13"class="col"></div>
</div> 
<div class="row">
  <div id="20" class="col"></div>  
  <div id="21"class="col"></div>
  <div id="22"class="col"></div>
  <div id="23"class="col"></div>
</div> 
<div class="row">
  <div id="30" class="col"></div>  
  <div id="31"class="col"></div>
  <div id="32"class="col"></div>
  <div id="33"class="col"></div>
</div> 
 <script>
var size = 4;
var player = 0;
var board = new Array(size);
for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
board[i] = new Array(size);
for (var j = 0; j < size; j++) {
   board[i][j] = 0;
    }
  }
 var div_elements = document.getElementsByClassName("col");
 for (var i = 0; i < div_elements.length;i++) {

     div_elements[i].addEventListener("click", function() {mclick(this);});
 }
var count=0;
 function mclick(obj) {
   if(match(div_elements.childNodes[0].nodeValue) == match(div_elements.childNodes[1].nodeValue)
   {
     obj.style.backgroundColor="white";

   }
   else{
    setTimeout(function(){ obj.style.backgroundColor="white" }, 1000);
   }
  }

 function shuffle() {
      var value;
    var text;
    var text_node;
    for (var i = 0; i < (size * size) ; i++) {

          value = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 8);
       board[Math.floor(i/4)][i %4] = value;
    }  

    for (var i = 0; i < div_elements.length; i++)
    {
        text = board[Math.floor(i/4)][i%4];
        text_node = document.createTextNode( text);
         div_elements[i].appendChild(text_node);

    }

 }



 shuffle();
</script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Before asking people to find the cause of an issue, please describe that issue: what is wrong with your code execution?

Answer (score 0):

You must be more specific. What kind of problem are you having? What are the error messages? What do you do that triggers the problem?

At least, put the code in a pastebin.com or something similar so that others don't need to setup a project for testing your whole stuff.

Comment: sorry i forgot to include. The problem is the match method does not read the div_elements value. and the assumption of this if I click 2 consecutive table and they are matched, it will set Timeout to revealed the value. if not matched, it will back in original state. I am confused about this. sorry again.